# Backup my custom list of Firefox search engines

Tags: firefox, backup, firefox-extensions, search-engines

I have started to use very often the search by keyword in Firefox with different search engines that I can add through this [addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-custom-search-engine/).

In order to search a word in French dictionary I simply type `fr` and the searched word, etc.

[image]

But the list cannot be synced to the Firefox account.

Is there a way to backup that list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the subject of Mozilla bug-report
[Bug 444284 : Sync search plugins](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=444284).

There is no solution to this request, except the following:

> **Workaround**
>
> Assuming copying from one PC to another
>
> 1. Close FF on both PCs
> 2. Navigate to your profile folder on the old PC: `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\`
> 3. Find file `search.json.mozlz4`
> 4. Copy file to USB/Cloud Service/FF Send
> 5. Download to new PC and copy to your profile folder (replace the existing file)
> 6. Open FF on your new PC and enjoy your search engines and keywords
>
> Note: when I reopened FF after doing this my default search engine had
> been changed, so you may need to manually reset the default.

You can copy the file `search.json.mozlz4` and use it as the backup.
This is a binary file, not in text/XML.

According to the comment by Yisroel Tech, this file is in
the `mozlz4` compressed format.

A utility for compressing and decompressing these files is
available in the project page of
[mozlz4](https://github.com/jusw85/mozlz4):

Extract search.json.lz4 :

```
$ ./mozlz4 search.json.mozlz4 search.json
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it *a binary file*, it's a file compressed with Mozilla's "mozLz4" text  compression format

Comment: @YisroelTech: Thanks for the information, I added this to my answer.

Comment: On Linux, the file is located at `~/.mozilla/firefox/<PROFILE>` in classic installation, `~/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/firefox/<PROFILE>` in snap, etc. - Testing with a new profile, I can confirm this also saves the keywords!